# Profiling Netty Performance

Tags: java, linux, netty

I'm writing a Netty application. The application is running on a 64 bit eight core linux box

The Netty application is a simple router that accepts requests (incoming pipeline) reads some metadata from the request and forwards the data to a remote service (outgoing pipeline).

This remote service will return one or more responses to the outgoing pipeline. The Netty application will route the responses back to the originating client (the incoming pipeline)

There will be thousands of clients. There will be thousands of remote services.

I'm doing some small scale testing (ten clients, ten remotes services) and I don't see the sub 10 millisecond performance I'm expecting at a 99.9 percentile. I'm measuring latency from both client side and server side.

I'm using a fully async protocol that is similar to SPDY. I capture the time (I just use System.nanoTime()) when we process the first byte in the FrameDecoder. I stop the timer just before we call channel.write(). I am measuring sub-millisecond time (99.9 percentile) from the incoming pipeline to the outgoing pipeline and vice versa.

I also measured the time from the first byte in the FrameDecoder to when a ChannelFutureListener callback was invoked on the (above) message.write(). The time was a high tens of milliseconds (99.9 percentile) but I had trouble convincing myself that this was useful data.

My initial thought was that we had some slow clients. I watched channel.isWritable() and logged when this returned false. This method did not return false under normal conditions

Some facts:

- We are using the NIO factories. We have not customized the worker size
- We have disabled Nagel (tcpNoDelay=true)
- We have enabled keep alive (keepAlive=true)
- CPU is idle 90+% of the time
- Network is idle
- The GC (CMS) is being invoked every 100 seconds or so for a very short amount of time

Is there a debugging technique that I could follow to determine why my Netty application is not running as fast as I believe it should?

It feels like channel.write() adds the message to a queue and we (application developers using Netty) don't have transparency into this queue. I don't know if the queue is a Netty queue, an OS queue, a network card queue or what. Anyway I'm reviewing examples of existing applications and I don't see any anti-patterns I'm following

Thanks for any help/insight

Comment: Your benchmarking approach might not be as accurate as you think.  Have a look at http://code.google.com/p/caliper/wiki/JavaMicrobenchmarks for some good insight into why.

Comment: maybe I am making a microbenchmark. But I am load testing the application while I am measuring latencies. Also, I'm making lots of measurements (1000 requests per second, 99.9th percentile over ten seconds). Clearly the client experience when the service is under load is unacceptable. How do I dig down in netty and figure out if the additional latency is my code, netty's code, the operating system, the network card, the network, etc? My code is apparently using less than a microsecond of wallclock time (as far as I can tell)

Comment: Is it an open-sourced project?
Did you find the issue?

Comment: it is not an open source project. I never found the issue

Comment: Why don't plug JProfiler on your Netty application and use it to analise the performance?

Answer (score 2):

Netty creates Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2 workers by default. 16 in your case. That means you can handle up to 16 channels simultaneously, other channels will wait untils you release the ChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream/SimpleChannelHandler.messageReceived handlers, so don't do heavy operations in these (IO) threads, otherwise you can stuck the other channels.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified your Netty version, but it sounds like Netty 3.
Netty 4 is now stable, and I would advise that you update to it as soon as possible.
You have specified that you want ultra low latency times, as well as tens of thousands of clients and services. This doesn't really mix well. NIO is inherently reasonably latent as opposed to OIO. However the pitfall here is that OIO probably wont be able to reach the number of clients you are hoping for. None the less I would use an OIO event loop / factory and see how it goes.

I myself have a TCP server, which takes around 30ms on localhost to send and receive and process a few TCP packets (measured from the time client opens a socket until server closes it). If you really do require such low latencies I suggest you switch away from TCP due to the SYN/ACK spam that is required to open a connection, this is going to use a large part of your 10ms.

Answer (score 0):

Measuring time in a multi-threaded environment is very difficult if you are using simple things like System.nanoTime(). Imagine the following on a 1 core system:

1. Thread A is woken up and begins processing the incoming request.
2. Thread B is woken up and begins processing the incoming request. But since we are working on a 1 core machine, this ultimately requires that Thread A is put on pause.
3. Thread B is done and performed perfectly fast.
4. Thread A resumes and finishes, but took twice as long as Thread B. Because you actually measured the time it took to finish for Thread A + Thread B.

There are two approaches on how to measure correctly in this case:

1. You can enforce that only one thread is used at all times.
   This allows you to measure the exact performance of the operation, **if the OS does not interfere.** Because in the above example Thread B can be outside of your program as well. A common approach in this case is to median out the interference, which will give you an **estimation** of the speed of your code.
   You can however assume, that on an otherwise idle multi-core system, there will be another core to process background tasks, so your measurement will *usually* not be interrupted. Setting this thread to high priority helps as well.
2. You use a more sophisticated tool that plugs into the JVM to actually measure the atomic executions and time it took for those, which will effectively remove outside interference almost completely. One tool would be [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/download.html), which is already integrated in NetBeans and available as a plugin for Eclipse.

As a general advice: it is not a good idea to use more threads than cores, unless you know that those threads will be blocked by some operation frequently. This is not the case when using non-blocking NIO for IO-operations as there is no blocking.

Therefore, in your special case, you would actually reduce the performance for clients, as explained above, because communication would be put on hold up to 50% of the time under high load. In worst case, that could cause a client to even run into a timeout, as there is no guarantee when a thread is actually resumed (unless you explicitly request fair scheduling).

Comment: "it is not a good idea to use more threads than cores (...) This is not the case when using non-blocking NIO" Totally agree with what you say, any idea why Netty uses cores * 2 for the number of threads by default then? I would as well have limited it to the number of cores.