# Netty worker and boss Thread configuration performance issue

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, netty, reactor-netty

Environment-
Netty 4.1.16 . java 8

Created a server, defined 2 boss and 8 worker thread and 100 Business Handler thread,

```
EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(2);
EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(8);
final EventExecutorGroup handlerThread = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(100); 
ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
bootstrap.group(bossGroup, workerGroup);
bootstrap.channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class);
bootstrap.childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
  @Override
  protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
    pipeline.addLast(new NettyDecoder()); 
    pipeline.addLast(new NettyEncoder());
    pipeline.addLast(handlerThread,"serverHandler",new ServerHandler()); 
  }
});
```

Problem is that i am not getting performance with this configuration. my server is only serves 35 requests 1 second.

if I change the boss thread = 1 and worker thread = 1, then also having same response size. serve 35 requests in this case also.

I am worried that is thread is working properly or not?

Question is for 1 worker thread it serves 35 requests so I have configured 8 worker Thread, So it should serve 36 * 8 = 288 requests in 1 second.

I am very new in netty. Kindly help. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to benchmark before you attempt to solve any performance problems. https://stackoverflow.com/q/14613615/1531971

Comment: Your calculation about Netty is right. You should server 288 requests with 8 worker threads. You should check what you are doing in ServerHandler